Root System $C2$ in Latex/TikZ
In this question it is asked and shown how to draw the root diagram for $G_2$ using the program TikZ. How can one do the same for the other rank $2$ root systems: $A2, $B2$ and $C2$? For example her is the case of $B2$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#/media/File:Root_system_B2.svg
I am especially interested in the case of $C2$.

Welcome. // How? I suggest spending some time on leraning Tikz. A starting point can be to look up all commands from the question you linked here: https://tikz.dev/ . Don't hesitate to modify the code or try your own. // The way your question is now will probably lead to a quick close ...

I am sorry but I do not see why my question is different to the one I linked to. What was that not closed? I am asking because  the TikZ code is probably out there and I would like to use a standard version rather than badly recreate a new version . . .  but then again maybe I don't understand how things work around here.

To add some context, the rank $2$ root systems are basics constructions in Lie theory and there has to be a standard TikZ code floating around on the web. I am looking for somebody to point me in the correct direction.

Let me try to explain how this community thinks and acts. // 1) You ask "how", not "where", which many here read as "do it for me". // 2) The example you linked is simple Tikz code. With a little learning any novice can modify it the way you need. This includes ... you as well. // 3) The format is 1 question ==  1 problem, each answer == 1 solution. Your problem statement is imprecise. Posting your code attempt would be more precise; that's why code is "the currency" here. // Hope this helps. Suggestion: don't argue, learn and do better.

Try searches like https://www.google.com/search?q=ctan.org+lie+theory , as when packages are there for you, you'll find them at ctan. This one (check the pdf) will probably not do ... https://ctan.org/pkg/lie-hasse

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rank-2-roots

Besides showing what you tried, you should also make your question self-sustained so that it remains useful even if the links stop working.

Ok, so I guess I can try to modify the G2 TikZ code. Since you say that the modification is so easy it should be possible for an AI site to do directly. I will give it a go.

Hm, don't expect too much from AI here, and spend more time on human learning. The last result I saw were close to what a toddler can do, regardless of subject ...

Here is how you can do this with the rank 2 roots package.

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{rank-2-roots}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {A,B,C,G}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.5]
        \begin{rootSystem}{\i}
        \roots
        \end{rootSystem}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}

